# how to print message for average of tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

My code is to print the average of tuples in a list and to return None if the list is empty. Right now this is my code

```
def average_vehicles(vehicle_records):
    """Return average of vehicles"""
    summ = 0
    num = 0
    average = 0
    if vehicle_records != []:
        for value in vehicle_records:            
            summ += value[1]
            num += 1
        average = summ / num
    else:
        average  = "None" 
    return average
```

I get the correct output for this test code:

```
some_records = [('2010-01-01',100),
            ('2010-01-02',200),
            ('2010-01-03',300)]
avg = average_vehicles(some_records)
print(avg)
```

However I can't get it to print "OK" for the following test code and I'm not sure why it isn't doing the job when everything else looks right, can someone please help?

```
some_records = []
avg = average_vehicles(some_records)
if avg is None:
   print('OK')
else:
   print('The function should return a None value')
```

Comment: Because you are returning the string `"None"` and not `None`. Change the code in the else to `average=None` and it should work.

Comment: by default avg is either `0` or some value! It never be `"None"` and not None object!

Comment: Furthermore, there's no need to calculate the sum in a loop. You can use the builtin `sum` and simplify your `average_vehicles` function to one line: `return sum(rec[1] for rec in vehicle_records)/len(vehicle_records) if vehicle_records else None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None shouldn't be a string but a None object.
Change the following line `average = "None"` to `average = None` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you're returning the string `"None"` instead of the object `None`

Answer (score 0):

`None` and `"None"` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_records = []
avg = average_vehicles(some_records)
if avg == "None":
   print('OK')
else:
   print('The function should return a None value')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_records = []
avg = average_vehicles(some_records)
if avg == 'None':
   print('OK')
else:
   print('The function should return a None value')
```

Explanation:

When we print the type of `avg` it is of type `str` but if we check `avg is None`,  in this `None` is of type `Nonetype`. So we need to check using "None" as `avg == 'None'`